# add a QStandardItem of type PushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to add items to QStandardItemModel all of these items are of type QStandardItem. I wanted to know if there was a way to attach a QPushButton to the model.
In other words are they any properties of QStandardItem that I could alter to make it appear as a push Button

Comment: You need only apperance or you need a behavior?

Comment: appearence and behaviour. Most importantly behaviour that could trigger item changed signal in a model

Comment: Use setItemWidget method of your view. It will give behaviour. If you want both - you shall create custom delegate.

Comment: My understanding is that qstandarditemmodels are for vanilla displays (text, icons, checkboxes), nothing particularly fancy.While it may be possible to do what you want, it would likely be much easier with qtreewidget (which has a setitemwidget method!), or if you want customization and speed and flexibility, go with qabstractitemmodel. That's my hunch, one of the qt ninjas here probably knows for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Using style sheets is your best bet. Here is an example where I styled the items in a `QListWidget` to look like tabs. A little massage can give it a button look.

```
/* make the property editor list look like tabs */
QListWidget#PropertyEditor_List 
{ 
  background-color: Transparent; 
  padding-right: 0px; 
  padding-top: 2px; 
  padding-left: 2px; 
}
QListWidget#PropertyEditor_List::item 
{
  padding: 3px; 
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 white, stop:1 Transparent); 
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(145,155,155); 
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(145,155,155);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(145,155,155);
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
QListWidget#PropertyEditor_List::item:hover, QListWidget#PropertyEditor_List::item:selected 
{ 
  background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(255,200,60), stop:0.039 rgb(255,200,60), stop:0.04 white, stop:0.4 white, stop:1 Transparent); 
  border-left-color: rgb(230,139,44);
}
QListWidget#PropertyEditor_List::item:selected 
{ 
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(255,200,60), stop:0.039 rgb(255,200,60), stop:0.04 white);
  border-left-color: rgb(230,139,44);
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: original question is about qstandarditemmodel not qlistwidget. And (as clarified in their comments) they wanted something that when clicked would emit a signal, not just appearance of a button.